# Как через php pdo отправлять пачкой запросы mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Работаем через PDO c mysql, это очень важно.
Делаю как тут http://php.net/manual/ru/pdo.prepared-statements.php

```
$stmt = $dbh->prepare ("INSERT INTO user (firstname, surname) VALUES (:f-name, :s-name)");
$stmt -> bindParam(':f-name', 'John');
$stmt -> bindParam(':s-name', 'Smith');
$stmt -> execute();
```

Как можно инсертов отправить много, по 100 по 1000 штук?

Что то никак не могу понять про процедуры

знаете как в mysql перечесляешь INSERT INTO user () VALUES (),(),(),();

Comment: Надо костыль писать, который создает строку с подготовленными параметрами, а потом передает их в execute массивом. Встроенного решения нет, можно библиотеку найти или решения в интернете (multiple insert pdo).

Comment: Почему вам исключаете вариант с последовательным исполнением? Я понимаю, что будет выигрыш в скорости, но настолько ли он для вас значим?

Comment: Ну вариант с послед уже работает. Просто по аналогии смотрю. Пачками быстрее вставляет. Хотя не замерял на сколько. Щас померяю в phpadmin и решу может не такой и большой выигрыш

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В pdo есть транзакции и подготовленные выражения

http://php.net/manual/ru/pdo.commit.php

```
$dbh->beginTransaction();

/* Вставка множества записей по принципу "все или ничего" */
$sql = 'INSERT INTO fruit
    (name, colour, calories)
    VALUES (?, ?, ?)';

$sth = $dbh->prepare($sql);

foreach ($fruits as $fruit) {
    $sth->execute(array(
        $fruit->name,
        $fruit->colour,
        $fruit->calories,
    ));
}

/* Фиксация изменений */
$dbh->commit();
```

Но я не уверен, что это поможет.

Comment: Ну это уже больше похоже на ответ по существу. попробую. если не это то значит ничего не поможет. спасибо

Comment: Не очень понятно, при чем здесь "mysql библиотека", но в режиме эмуляции ПДО прекрасно отправляет множественные запросы. Другое дело, что автору нужен множественный инсерт

Comment: Поддерживаю ответ - пачка инсёртов/апдейтов через транзакцию гораздо быстрее пачки инсёртов/апдейтов без транзакции.

Comment: @ГончаровАлександр во-первых, это верно только для innodb с дефолтными настройками, а во-вторых есть еще и третий вариант, описанный автором вопроса.