# Множественный запрос на добавление в цикле

Tags: php, sql, postgresql, pdo

Имеется таблица из трех столбцов, например (id, id_1, column_1), где столбец id - автоинкрементный, id_1 - будет всегда одно значение добавляться с типом int (например, будет всегда 1), а column_1 - строковый тип, будет считываться из поля input. 
Проблема в том, что я не знаю как лучше организовать запрос, и возможно лучше делать через цикл, потому что количество значений вводимое в input заранее неизвестно. Генерация input'ов происходит на лету, добавляться может как 3 значения так и 5. Пример бы не помешал, заранее спасибо.

Comment: у вас два пути, оба из них будут использовать цикл. Первый - это использвоаие инструкции `insert into ... values (...), (...)` когда одним запросом вставляются несоклько записей. Тут в цикле вы будете генирировать само тело запроса. Второй вариант, это подготовленные выражения и вставка в цикле по одной строке.

Comment: очень сильно хочется пример =/

Comment: пример по второму варианту https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/575819/223826

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *очень сильно хочется пример*

Принцип такой:

```
// Массив значений
$array = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'];

// Начало sql-запрса
$sql = 'INSERT INTO `Имя таблицы` (`id_1`, `column_1`) VALUES ';

$temp = [];
// Генерация sql-запроса в цикле
foreach($array as $value){
    $temp[] = "(1, '$value')";
}

// Объединение sql-запроса
$sql .= join(', ', $temp) . ';';

// Просмотр sql-запроса
echo $sql;
```

Результат:

```
INSERT INTO `Имя таблицы` ( `id_1`, `column_1` ) VALUES (1, 'a'), (1, 'b'), (1, 'c'), (1, 'd'), (1, 'e');
```

Comment: в цикле все таки плейсхолдеры надо генерить, а не значения подставлять. и да, такой способ обычно имеет ограничение на число вставляемых записей. с 3-5 записей как у автора проблемы не будет, а вот если тысяча, то не вставятся, ну или вставятся но не везде.

Comment: @teran я полностью с вами согласен. Тут просто показал принцип генерации запросов в циклах.

Comment: Спасибо всем за ответы.